# How to add the value for each label to pie legend

Tags: jquery, charts, chart.js

i want to add the label value for the pie legend, but i can only see the label without the value.

This is what i see[image]

but i want to see the value for each letter

```
var ctx = $('#chart').find('canvas').get(0).getContext('2d');
var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx).Pie(data2,options);
var legend = myPieChart.generateLegend();
$('#chart').find('.legend').html(legend);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the legend template to include the value next to the label like;

```
legendTemplate : "<ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\"><% for (var i=0; i<segments.length; i++){%><li><span style=\"background-color:<%=segments[i].fillColor%>\"></span><%if(segments[i].label){%><%=segments[i].label%> : <%=segments[i].value%> <%}%></li><%}%></ul>",
```

```js
var pieData = [{
    value: 24.8,
    color: "#40af49",
    label: "African American"
}, {
    value: 2.9,
    color: "#ac558a",
    label: "Other"
}, {
    value: 5.7,
    color: "#f05541",
    label: "Multi-Racial, Not Hispanic"
}, {
    value: 19.1,
    color: "#3ac2d0",
    label: "Hispanic/Latino"
}, {
    value: 6.5,
    color: "#faaf3c",
    label: "Asian"
}, {
    value: 41,
    color: "#4287b0",
    label: "White/Caucasian"
}];

var helpers = Chart.helpers;
var race = new Chart(document.getElementById("race").getContext("2d")).Doughnut(pieData, {
    tooltipTemplate: "<%if (label){%><%=label%>: <%}%><%= value %>%",
    legendTemplate : "<ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\"><% for (var i=0; i<segments.length; i++){%><li><span style=\"background-color:<%=segments[i].fillColor%>\"></span><%if(segments[i].label){%><%=segments[i].label%> : <%=segments[i].value%>% <%}%></li><%}%></ul>",
    animateRotate: true
});
var legendHolder = document.createElement('div');
legendHolder.innerHTML = race.generateLegend();

// Include a html legend template after the module doughnut itself
helpers.each(legendHolder.firstChild.childNodes, function (legendNode, index) {
    helpers.addEvent(legendNode, 'mouseover', function () {
        var activeSegment = race.segments[index];
        activeSegment.save();
        race.showTooltip([activeSegment]);
        activeSegment.restore();
    });
});
helpers.addEvent(legendHolder.firstChild, 'mouseout', function () {
    race.draw();
});

race.chart.canvas.parentNode.parentNode.appendChild(legendHolder.firstChild);
```

```html
<script src="http://www.chartjs.org/assets/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="race" width="250" height="250" style="width: 250px; height: 250px;"></canvas>
```

EDIT:

if you would like to display the percentage the value represents you can access the `total` within the template like so

`legendTemplate: "<ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\"><% for (var i=0; i<segments.length; i++){%><li><span style=\"background-color:<%=segments[i].fillColor%>\"></span><%if(segments[i].label){%><%=segments[i].label%> : <%=(segments[i].value/total)*100%>% <%}%></li><%}%></ul>",`

```js
var data = [{
    value: 301,
    color: "#F7464A",
    highlight: "#FF5A5E",
    label: "Red"
}, {
    value: 120,
    color: "#FDB45C",
    highlight: "#FFC870",
    label: "Yellow"
}, {
    value: 0,
    color: "#3BA5D9",
    highlight: "#3BA5D9",
    label: "Blue"
}]






//canvases
var chart = document.getElementById("chart").getContext("2d");

var helpers = Chart.helpers;
//charts
var myChart = new Chart(chart).Doughnut(data, {
    tooltipTemplate: "<%if (label){%><%=label%>: <%}%><%= value %>",
    legendTemplate: "<ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\"><% for (var i=0; i<segments.length; i++){%><li><span style=\"background-color:<%=segments[i].fillColor%>\"></span><%if(segments[i].label){%><%=segments[i].label%> : <%= Math.floor(((segments[i].value/total)*100)+0.5) %>% <%}%></li><%}%></ul>",
    animateRotate: true
});


var legendHolder = document.createElement('div');
legendHolder.innerHTML = myChart.generateLegend();

// Include a html legend template after the module doughnut itself
helpers.each(legendHolder.firstChild.childNodes, function (legendNode, index) {
    helpers.addEvent(legendNode, 'mouseover', function () {
        var activeSegment = race.segments[index];
        activeSegment.save();
        race.showTooltip([activeSegment]);
        activeSegment.restore();
    });
});
helpers.addEvent(legendHolder.firstChild, 'mouseout', function () {
    myChart.draw();
});

myChart.chart.canvas.parentNode.parentNode.appendChild(legendHolder.firstChild);
```

```html
<script src="http://www.quincewebdesign.com/cdn/Chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks! that's giving me the value but the percentages are not good. this pie chart is for multiple choice quiz. lets say i have 4 answers. 5 choose A and 5 choose B. with the template you gave me i can see A: 5%, B: 5%. i need to see 50%

Comment: Amazing! any chance i can round the percentages? 33% instead of 33.3333%?

Comment: yeah use math.floor or you could do the trick of adding 0.5 then using math.floor to simulate rounding to the closet whole number

Comment: Thanks you very much for your quick answer! i have another question. not about that but maybe you know. my data contains only the answers user clicked on. so if 5 choose A and 5 choose B and no one clicked on C and D, i want anyway to show C : 0%, D : 0%

Comment: you just need to add it to the chart with the value of 0 and that way they will appear on the legend (not the chart as they take up 0 space being value 0) see the updated second example for what i mean

Comment: But that's means i need to change my data, which built dynamically to what user answered. if no one click on C it won't be at the data. i thought maybe the chart can detect alone if C isn't there. never mind i'll find something. thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I would say that would be the preferred option as other wise you would have to code into the front end all the options that can be passed and do a bit of preprocessing to workout what is not there as the chart (or the legend which comes from the chart) needs to have the data. IMO it would be a pain in the arse in the front end as any changes to options mean editing this front end chart

Comment: @user2587454 if the original question is answered here you can mark this as the answer, if you have any more questions just start up a new question to discuss those concerns